# Make text underlined in xcode

Tags: uitextfield, underline

Hey I'm making an app that requires a certain part of a text view's text to be underlined. is there a simple way to do this like for making it bold and italics or must i make and import a custom font? thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This is what i did. It works like butter.

1) Add `CoreText.framework` to your Frameworks.

2) import `<CoreText/CoreText.h>` in the class where you need underlined label.

3) Write the following code.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"My Messages"];
[attString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName
                  value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCTUnderlineStyleSingle]
                  range:(NSRange){0,[attString length]}];
self.myMsgLBL.attributedText = attString;
self.myMsgLBL.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TextFieldWithUnderLine : UITextField

@end

#import "TextFieldWithUnderLine.h"

@implementation TextFieldWithUnderLine

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    //Get the current drawing context
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    //Set the line color and width
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.5f);
    //Start a new Path
    CGContextBeginPath(context);

    // offset lines up - we are adding offset to font.leading so that line is drawn right below the characters and still characters are visible.
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x, self.font.leading + 4.0f);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width, self.font.leading + 4.0f);

    //Close our Path and Stroke (draw) it
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 6.0 [`UILabel`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html), [`UITextField`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) and [`UITextView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html) support displaying [attributed strings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) using the attributedText property.

**Usage:**

```
NSMutableAttributedString *aStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"text"];
[aStr addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:NSUnderlineStyleSingle range:NSMakeRange(0,2)];
label.attributedText = aStr;
```

Comment: something isn't working out; here is my code do you see anything that stands out as faulty? NSMutableAttributedString *aStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:BookTitle.text];
        [aStr addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:NSUnderlineStyleSingle range:NSMakeRange(0,2)];
        BookTitle.attributedText = aStr;

Comment: where BookTitle is a textFeild