# iOS7 - How to underline a UITextField

Tags: ios, ios7, nsmutablestring

I have looked at (and tried the code snippets) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423776/make-text-underlined-in-xcode), but wonder if something has come up in iOS7? More likely, I'm doing something wrong.

My code is as follows:

```
import <CoreText/CoreText.h>

    NSString *tempString1 = [currentMemory valueForKey:@"title"];

    NSMutableAttributedString *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:tempString1];
        [attString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName
                    value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCTUnderlineStyleSingle]
                    range:(NSRange){0,[attString length]}];
        self.titleLabel.attributedText = attString;
        self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

I'm getting this compile error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSConcreteMutableAttributedString initWithString:: nil value'

If I use plain text

```
self.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tempString1];
```

it works fine. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think your dictionary, currentMemory, is returning nil for the key "title" and that nil is causing the exception in init.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Why would this work when the result is a plain NSString? I am logging the current Memory, and it's full when I am using the NSString, and empty when using the attributed string.. weird..